# Addition of schoolwork as an off-topic closure

Tags: feature-request

Many times we happen to close questions due to someone giving their home assignment to people on Stack Overflow without trying anything themselves.

I believe we are not a community of assignment-solvers and posting exercises without trying anything is something that annoys the vast majority of the community.

That's why I suggest the addition of "Show us what you have tried so far" or "Stack Overflow is not a place for posting schoolwork" as an off-topic closure reason.

These kinds of questions are almost always closed anyway so a way of standardizing it with links and a good explanation will be beneficial for the community and for the poor poster who didn't read the FAQ.

Comment: This is not related to homework (in fact, adding that it is actually homework may press answerers to post a subtly different answer (hopefully)). A random [counterexample](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38823053/2564301), which *also* blatantly asks for code - even in the comments to answers!

Comment: An example of such a question is *[Python recursion challenge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544604)*.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with homework questions as long they accomplish the overall policies already setup for the site.

Comment: ***Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.***
Most don't attempt to solve the problem except by giving it to us in order to solve it for them.

Comment: @Bharel That's exactly my point yes.

Comment: @Bharel _"Most don't attempt to solve the problem except by giving it to us in order to solve it for them"_ In such case downvote/closevote/flag the question as _too broad_ / _unclear_ and move on.

Comment: @Bharel so how is the issue the homework question? The issue is "no summary of work done so far and no description of problem". The fact it's a homework is irrelevant.

Comment: @Patrice so how about this as a close reason?

Comment: @Bharel As mentioned, there are already enough close reasons for that situation. We don't need _special_ additional ones.

Comment: The correct closure reason for these types of "write/debug my code for me" questions is hidden under "off-topic". That's probably why you missed it, @Bharel. Of course, "unclear what you're asking" often works just as well. It is always unclear what someone is asking when they dump the text of an assignment, since there is no question.